# Как с помощью Retrofit 2.0 отправить данные в JSON на сервер и получить ответ?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Только начал читать про `Retrofit 2.0` до этого использовал `HttpURLConnection`.

Как я работаю с `HttpURLConnection`, формирую `Json` перевожу его в `byte[]`, ставлю `header` в конешен, таймаут, mime тип, и еще несколько свойств `urlConnection.setRequestProperty()` и это все летит на сервер.

В ответ я получаю тоже `Json` с результатом в зависимости от запроса...

Хочу перейти на `Retrofit 2.0` насколько я понял это более гибкая библиотека и т.д.

Так вот все примеры которые я нахожу показывают как работать с сериализацией.

Можно как то просто отправить байты и получить ответ с сервера?

Или это не правильный подход в случае когда работаешь с `Retrofit 2.0`?